# NSArray of NSDictionaries - filtering by dictionary value and return unique array object

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

So suppose I have an `NSArray` populated with hundreds of `NSDictionary` objects.

All dictionary objects have a value for the key `name` but these values names may appear more than once in different objects.

I need to be able to filter this NSArray to only return one object per unique `name` attribute (whichever object, first or last, I don't care).

This is how far I've got but obviously my `filtered` array contains all objects rather than only unique ones.

I'm thinking there must be a way to tell the predicate to limit its results to only one / first match?

```
NSArray *allObjects = ... // This is my array of NSDictionaries                                                                                              
NSArray *uniqueNames = [allObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.name"];
NSArray *filtered = [allObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self.name IN %@)", uniqueNames]];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *uniqueObjects = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:allObjects.count];
for (NSDictionary *object in allObjects) {
    [uniqueObjects setObject:object forKey:object[@"name"]];
}
```